# What is the worst thing that can happen to me if I use a laptop that I had lent to a person who might have been involved in shady activities?

Tags: legal, crime

I lent my old laptop to a person who was in need of it in order to work abroad during autumn. Recently though, I learnt from a trusted source that his father had faced trouble with the police in the past due to some minor illegal activities. His parents are divorced. He seems a great guy and I do not think he maintains frequent contact with his dad. However, from the moment we learnt about his father's shady past, my own parents have become paranoid about this laptop. They insist that I should not take it back because I might get in trouble, since it is an electronic device and it might have been used for illegal activities, it might be "bugged", it might contain a GPS tracker etc.

My question is, are they indeed paranoid or is there any kernel of truth in their worries? What is the worst case/most extreme scenario that can happen if I take it back, from a security and personal safety perspective? In any case, I do intend to format it and reinstall Windows,

P.S: Yes I am aware now that I shoud NOT have lent the laptop in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the particulars here but there are indeed ***possible*** justified concerns.

Likely immediate concerns:

- Kiddie Porn possesion (even if you are not aware of it)
- Malware, Botware, similar
- Sensitive information; Legal, Criminal, Classified

Format and reinstall is not sufficient. You need to actively **wipe** the drives.

Less likely would be hardware modification to include trackers, but begs the question as to what purpose? *Possibly to find and recover hidden information on it or in it?*

Even if there is nothing on or in the laptop, will powerful entities turn their attention toward you?

You will need to evaluate the cost/risk factors for yourself.

Comment: I personally believe that the *powerful entities* either won't bother, or (if they have attention over the OP) quickly determine that the OP is not directly and actively involved into any criminal action

Answer (score 1):

> his father had faced trouble with the police in the past due to some **minor** illegal activities (emphasis mine)

That looks a bit too much to me. `The sins of the fathers do not fall on the children` someone said. This information is not enough to judge a person's accountability.

In infosec, there are *two* categories of laptops: those you owned all the time since you unboxed them (from package with anti-tampering seal provided by manufacturer*), those that you left to an evil maid for some short time, and of course those that were tampered by the three-letter-agency at the factory (this is called supply-chain attack).

> His parents are divorced

This is not relevant for the question

> from the moment we learnt about his father's shady past, my own parents have become paranoid about this laptop. They insist that I should not take it back because I might get in trouble

I believe this is the true problem. I don't also want to judge about your parents, but you should be very well adult to take you conscious and educated decisions about what people hanging out with.

> it might have been used for illegal activities, it might be "bugged", it might contain a GPS tracker etc.

Okay, let's **assume** the laptop was involved in illegal activities. `Bugs` can be tracking software, or hardware tampers depending on the criminal level. A GPS tracker should likely be a *hardware* tamper, because most *laptops* on stores do not equip a GPS hardware. And you said your laptop is **old**, so it is extremely unlikely that it ships with a GPS module. I personally never bought a *laptop* with a GPS.

Indeed, internet activity can be monitored and MAC address known to other parties. Police? Drug cartels?

Things get worse from here. With the little information provided in the question and the wide scope of *crime*.

**Assuming** something *illegal* was done (to what extend? small dealing of drugs? international bribery? [watching porn in Uganda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pornography_laws_by_region#cite_note-23)? military secrets trading?), we have no clue or evidence whether the borrower installed executable software or just browsed the dark web with Tor.

What you can really do is to format the disk(s), take a good look at signs of tampering on the case and sleep on. Really, this all looks to me like you are getting too much influence from your parent's **unjustified** paranoia.

From the legal standpoint, according to the jurisdiction you live in, hanging out with someone involved in criminal activities doesn't make you a criminal directly. Lending laptops neither. And you shouldn't be required to break all ties with someone whose **father** did something wrong/unlawful. It's your moral choice. Not your parents'.

*Today I unboxed a Nokia phone with a simple `VOID` anti-tamper tape on the package, that's why I mentioned